# C2DM advice on implementation

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

Fellow struggling programmers,

I've consulted all the documentation concerning c2dm but am still looking for some advice. Do I need to implement a service within my application to listen for the Intents created when the google server pushes them to the device?

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

The documentation states it will wake up the app when the Intent is received by having the correct Intent filters and permissions in the app manifest. But how is that possible when the app isn't even loaded into memory? How does the OS know where to go?

Seems to me like I need to have a background service with those permissions which will then start my app when a notification is received.

Anyone have some insight on this idea?

perhaps someone who has implemented a background service using c2dm

or found it to be unneeded.

Comment: i'm not sure but ... first: when you're installing application system update "internal intent database" .... second: i'm pretty sure that C2DM is not push but long pool internal android service when it gets message it "send broadcast" which mean it starts all apps with specific intent fillters and pass parameters to selected C2DMBroadcastReceiver ... just take code from http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/checkout (`C2DMBaseReceiver`, `C2DMBroadcastReceiver`, `C2DMessaging` are common) you need to implement only `C2DMReceiver` that extends `C2DMBaseReceiver` and `DeviceRegistrar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intent filters do not require an application or service to be started. When the OS sees that an event has occurred that you have registered an Intent filter for, it will launch the Intent that the Intent filter is attached to as indicated in your manifest.

Comment: A service would be useful if he intents to do some long slow tasks when receiving the notification.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't need a service. It depends on what kind of reaction you need to a message. If you want to start an activity - feel free to do so straight from the C2DM message receiver.

By the way, the C2DM intents are not service intents. They're receiver intents. A service cannot catch them even if it wants. On the API level, you can't fire an intent *per se* - you have call `startActivity()`, or `start/bindService()`, or `sendBroadcast()`. Depending on the API called, the system will match the intent against activities, or services, or receivers.

I've implemented C2DM. In my case, I do have a service - but that's only because the reaction to a C2DM message in my app is a UI-less HTTP request that may take some time. This seems a rather common pattern in the grand scheme of things - a C2DM is only a trigger, it only tells an app that new data await at the back-end. In this scenario, a service would quietly query the back-end for the said new data and process them. That's my case. But it does not have to be this way.

A receiver alone is not a good vehicle for HTTP because receiver objects are transient - once an intent is delivered, Android assumes that the receiver is done and discards it. After that happens, the app's process has no running objects and is subject for shutdown anytime. A service, on the other hands, once started, runs until it's explicitly done (`stopService()` is called). That tells Android that the app is doing something, please don't terminate. A running service is not a rock solid guarantee that the app won't be shut down in case of a low memory condition, but it's better than nothing.

Technically speaking, your app is running even if the only thing running is a broadcast receiver. Android will start the app (the process, not the main activity) when a C2DM message arrives. The user won't know unless you flash some UI. It's up to you which other components of the app to invoke from the receiver.